# Actualización (detalle en la sentencia sql)- Paginación no funciona en mi código PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Buenos días una vez más vengo a ustedes porque ya en sql ya pude resolver pero ahora el detalle está en php que al momento de consultar en php no me funciona la paginación y no sé por qué, me da un error el cual dice el siguiente:

**Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in CODE 80**

En mi tabla solo aparece la paginación el número 1 y no me muestra la información como debería.

El código es el siguiente:

```
include('is_logged.php');
require_once ("../config/db.php");
require_once ("../config/conexion.php");

include "../sweet.php";

//Tiempo
ini_set('date.timezone','America/Mexico_City');
$hoy = date('d/m/Y');
$ayer = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('-1 day'));

$action = (isset($_REQUEST['action'])&& $_REQUEST['action'] !=NULL)?$_REQUEST['action']:'';
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $numero_factura=intval($_GET['id']);

    if($_SESSION['usuario']=='admin' || $_SESSION['usuario']=='ADMIN')  {
        $del1="delete from facturas where numero_factura='".$numero_factura."'";
        $del2="delete from detalle_factura where numero_factura='".$numero_factura."'";
        if ($delete1=mysqli_query($con,$del1) and $delete2=mysqli_query($con,$del2)) {
?>
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <strong>Aviso!</strong> Datos eliminados exitosamente
            </div>

            <script>
                location.reload();
                setInterval("actualizar()",5000);
            </script>

    <?php
        }else {
        ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <strong>Error!</strong> No se puedo eliminar los datos
            </div>
    <?
        }
    } else  {
        echo '
        <script>
            jQuery(function(){
                swal("No tiene acceso",
                "Error",
                "error");});
            setTimeout(function(){
               window.location.href="registros.php";
            }
            ,1500);
        </script>';
    }
}

if($action == 'ajax'){
    // escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
    $q = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_REQUEST['q'], ENT_QUOTES)));
    $sTable = "facturas f JOIN clientes c JOIN users u JOIN medicos m JOIN detalle_factura d JOIN productos p";
    $sWhere = "";
    $sWhere.=" ON f.id_cliente = c.id_cliente AND f.id_vendedor = u.user_id AND f.id_medico = m.id_medico AND d.id_producto = p.id_producto AND d.numero_factura = f.numero_factura";
    if ( $_GET['q'] != "" ) {
        $sWhere.= " and (c.nombre_cliente like '%$q%' or f.numero_factura like '%$q%' or f.debe1 like '%$q%' or f.total_venta like '%$q%' or f.estatus like '%$q%' or m.nombre_medico like '%$q%' or p.nombre_producto like '%$q%')";
    }
    $sWhere.=" GROUP BY c.id_cliente,f.numero_factura order by f.fecha_factura desc";
    
    include 'pagination.php'; //include pagination file
    
    //pagination variables
    $page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page']))?$_REQUEST['page']:1;
    $per_page = 10; //how much records you want to show
    $adjacents  = 4; //gap between pages after number of adjacents
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
    
    //Count the total number of row in your table*/
    $count_query   = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $sTable  $sWhere");
    $row= mysqli_fetch_array($count_query);
    $numrows = $row['numrows'];
    $total_pages = ceil($numrows/$per_page);
    $reload = './facturas.php';
    
    //main query to fetch the data
    $sql="SELECT d.*, GROUP_CONCAT(p.nombre_producto SEPARATOR ' | '), f.*, c.*, u.*, p.*, m.* FROM  $sTable $sWhere LIMIT $offset,$per_page";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    
    //loop through fetched data
    if ($numrows>0){
        echo mysqli_error($con);
        ?>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-hover" border="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="info">
                        <th class='text-center'># recibo</th>
                        <th class='text-center'>Fecha</th>
                        <th>Paciente</th>
                        <th>Estudios</th>
                        <th class='text-center'>Total</th>
                        <th class='text-center'>¿Pagado?</th>
                        <th class='text-center'>Acciones</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            <tbody>
        <?
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                $id_factura=$row['id_factura'];
                $numero_factura=$row['numero_factura'];
                $fecha=date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row['fecha_factura']));
                $nombre_cliente=$row['nombre_cliente'];
                $telefono_cliente=$row['telefono_cliente'];
                $email_cliente=$row['email_cliente'];
                $edad_cliente=$row['edad'];
                $nombre_vendedor=$row['nombre']." ".$row['apellidos'];
                $total_venta=$row['total_venta'];
                $debe_pago=$row['debe1'];
                $debe_cantidad=$row['debe2'];
                $nota=$row['nota'];
                $id_cliente=$row['id_cliente'];
                $id_medico=$row['id_medico'];
                $n_medico=$row['nombre_medico'];
                $estudios=$row["GROUP_CONCAT(p.nombre_producto SEPARATOR ' | ')"];

                if (Empty($debe_cantidad)) {
                    $debe_cantidad_2 = "";
                } 
                else {
                    $debe_cantidad_2 = " = $".$debe_cantidad;
                }
        ?>
                
                <tr>
                    <td class='text-center'><?php echo $numero_factura; ?></td>
                    <td class='text-center'><?php if($fecha== $hoy) { echo "<span style='font-weight:bold; color:#16a085;'>Hoy</span>"; } if($fecha == $ayer) { echo "<span style='font-weight:bold; color:#833471;'>Ayer</span>"; } if($fecha != $hoy  and $fecha !=  $ayer) { echo $fecha; }?></td>
                    <td><a href="historial_paciente.php?idcliente=<?php echo $id_cliente; ?>" title="<?php echo "ID paciente: ".$id_cliente."\nEdad del paciente: ".$edad_cliente."\nAtendio: ".$nombre_vendedor."\nDoctor/a: ".$n_medico."\nTeléfono: ".$telefono_cliente."\nCorreo: ".$email_cliente."\nNota: ".$nota;?>"><?php echo $nombre_cliente;?></a></td>
                    <td class='text-left' style="width:25%; font-size:12px;"><?php echo $estudios; ?></td>
                    <td  class='text-center'>$<?php echo number_format($total_venta,2); ?></td>
                    <td  class='text-center'>
                        <?php 
                            if ($debe_pago == "Sí" or empty($debe_pago)) {
                                echo '<span class="label label-success" style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bolder;">Sí</span>';
                            } else {
                                echo '<span class="label label-danger" style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bolder;">No'.$debe_cantidad_2.'</span>';
                                }
                        ?>
                    </td>
                <td  class='text-center'>
                    <a href="editar_registro.php?id_factura=<?php echo $id_factura; ?>" class='btn btn-default' title='Editar comprobante de análisis clínico' ><img src="img/editar.png" alt="editar" width="20" height="20"></a>
                    <a href="#" class='btn btn-default' title='Descargar comprobante de análisis clínico' onclick="imprimir_factura('<?php echo $id_factura;?>');"><img src="img/pdf2.png" alt="imprimir" width="20" height="20"></a>
                    <a href="#" class='btn btn-default' title='Eliminar comprobante de análisis clínico' onclick="eliminar('<?php echo $numero_factura; ?>')"><img src="img/eliminar.png" alt="eliminar" width="20" height="20"></a>
                </td>

                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
            </tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=7>
                    <span class="pull-right"><? echo paginate($reload, $page, $total_pages, $adjacents); ?></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

**El error me aparece en esta linea:**

$numrows = $row['numrows'];

**Asi deberia de aparecer con la paginacion de todos los resultados:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Pero me aparece asi:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me pueden ayudar con este error, se los super agradeceria muchisimo.

**Actualización 23-11-2021**

Viendo el conteo de registros que tengo en mi tabla veo que me desgloza las cantidades, ósea, en vez de que me diga el total general me da un total desglosado.

en el codigo de conteo lo tengo asi:

```
$sTable = "facturas f JOIN clientes c JOIN users u JOIN medicos m JOIN detalle_factura d JOIN productos p";
    $sWhere = "";
    $sWhere.=" ON f.id_cliente = c.id_cliente AND f.id_vendedor = u.user_id AND f.id_medico = m.id_medico AND d.id_producto = p.id_producto AND d.numero_factura = f.numero_factura";
    $sWhere.=" GROUP BY c.id_cliente,f.numero_factura order by f.fecha_factura desc";

    $count_query   = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $sTable $sWhere");
    $row= mysqli_fetch_array($count_query);
    $numrows = $row['numrows'];
    $total_pages = ceil($numrows/$per_page);
    $reload = './facturas.php';
```

$sql="SELECT f.*, c.*, u.*, p.*, m.*, d.*, GROUP_CONCAT(p.nombre_producto SEPARATOR ' | ') FROM $sTable $sWhere LIMIT $offset,$per_page";

Por que al quitar el limitador y el conteo me regresa todos los registros pero si lo tengo solo me devuelve uno solo en paginación.

**lo quiero así:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**y me lo devuelve asi...**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es como le hago para que me de el total general??

Comment: Te falta la clausula `WHERE`

Comment: Literalmente no le dices `WHERE` en la cláusula. Armas todo el string pero nunca dices la palabra mágica.

Comment: En donde no la pongo? perdon ando algo estresado y mi estres no me permite ver donde?

Comment: No necesitas WHERE porque estás poniendo los filtros ON (sobre los JOIN). No obstante, no estaría mal que construyeras tu consulta mejor y más ordenada, poniendo la condición que va con cada JOIN no todos los JOIN seguidos y luego todas las condiciones seguidas. Luego, para el Notice que te está dando, seguramente te está diciendo en qué línea del código se produce, pues mira a ver qué tienes raro por ahí. Ah, y recuerda este consejo: a veces basta con desconectar un rato para luego volver al código y verlo más claro.

Comment: Muchas gracias @JoséCarlosPHP si de hecho es lo que ando tratando de hacer pero por mas de que ando viendo cual es el error no veo como resolverlo, he estado investigando pero no me da nada en concreto, ósea con consultas apartes sin problemas pero en una sola consulta veo que la paginación no pasa de 1 y no se por que sea el motivo de esto. Si me pudieras ayudar o guiar te lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Lo primero es comprobar si la consulta de recuento del total está funcioando como se espera. Estoy seguro de que $total_pages es 1, y es porque la consulta del recuento te está fallando. eso encajaría con el Notice, porque no estás obteniendo ningún resultado y al intentar usar $row['numrows'] te dice eso de Trying to access array offset on value of type null. Entonces, revisa bien la consulta de recuento.

Comment: Puedes usar mysqli_error() para conocer el posible error, o casi mejor puedes hacer que te pinte la consulta entera, copiarla, e irte a phpMyAdmin o similar y ejecutarla, así es más fácil ver el error, porque puedes ir editando la consulta conforme pruebas, ponerla en varias líneas para que sea más clara, etc. Prueba y me cuentas.

Comment: Hola @JoséCarlosPHP imprimo numrows con echo y da 1 sobre el mysqli_error() este donde lo uso?

Comment: Cuando mysqli_query() devuelve false (lo suyo es comprobarlo), entonces se usa mysqli_error() para conocer el error. Pero en tu caso, si obtienes 1 como $numrows, la consulta no está dando error, pero no se está comportando como quieres porque sólo te cuenta un registro. Revisa la consulta de recuento para que dé un resultado correcto.

Comment: Buenos dias @JoséCarlosPHP ya estube checando en PHPMYADMIN y me sale todo normal sin errores y me muestra todos los registros pero si quito esta linea en $sWhere.=" GROUP BY c.id_cliente,f.numero_factura order by f.fecha_factura desc"; y lo dejo así $sWhere.="  order by f.fecha_factura desc"; me muestra todo la paginación pero mal la sentencia por que no estoy agrupando nada, no se si sea ese el detalle con el numrows....

Answer (score 0):

Es por el GROUP BY c.id_cliente,f.numero_factura.
Con eso, el count(*) te lo hace agrupando.

Tienes dos alternativas:

- **Construir la consulta de forma que no agrupe**.

Creo que estás listando facturas, por lo que podrías simplemente contar los registros de facturas:

```
$count_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows FROM facturas");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($count_query);
$numrows = $row['numrows'];
```

- **Contar los resultados de la consulta actual**.

Según parece, la consulta actual de recuento te devuelve tantos resultados como el número total de resultados que buscas, por lo que podrías contar esos resultados:

```
$count_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $sTable $sWhere");
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($count_query);
```